# MYSQL Trigger to create horizontal table from vertical

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have a table with this vertical structure. The Data comes from an external company so i have do deal with it.

```
+----+-----------+------+--------+
| id | status_id | key  | value  |
+----+-----------+------+--------+
|  1 |       100 | key1 | value1 |
|  2 |       100 | key2 | value2 |
|  3 |       100 | key3 | value3 |
|  4 |       200 | key1 | value1 |
|  5 |       200 | key2 | value2 |
|  6 |       200 | key3 | value3 |
+----+-----------+------+--------+
```

Now i wanted to create a horizontal table from this data with a trigger after insert, so that i become this structure..

```
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
| status_id |  key1  |  key2  |  key3  |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
|       100 | value1 | value2 | value3 |
|       200 | value1 | value2 | value3 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

The status_id becomes unique so i tried an `INSERT` with `ON DUPLICATE KEY` but i don't know how do i have to write it that the value from key becomes the field name for the insert.

Many greetings
Kevin

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

Did you looked into Pivot Table ? It may help you.

Useful link : http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

Other thread with similar question : [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: Yes i have read this, but it does not solve my problem. I want to create a trigger and got `NEW.key` and `NEW.value` but how can i use the `NEW.key`as the fieldname for the insert, especially for the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` part.